# Disable localization in favor of just English language as default.

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

I do not want localization support in ASP.NET Boilerplate, please let me know how can I disable it (if possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Comment out these lines in [DefaultLanguagesCreator.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/63f6e3b6147b6df7a08b09a53dad562c57dac17c/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/Seed/Host/DefaultLanguagesCreator.cs#L19-L28):

   ```
   private static List<ApplicationLanguage> GetInitialLanguages()
   {
       return new List<ApplicationLanguage>
       {
           new ApplicationLanguage(null, "en", "English", "famfamfam-flags gb"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "ar", "العربية", "famfamfam-flags sa"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "de", "German", "famfamfam-flags de"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "it", "Italiano", "famfamfam-flags it"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "fr", "Français", "famfamfam-flags fr"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "pt-BR", "Portuguese", "famfamfam-flags br"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "tr", "Türkçe", "famfamfam-flags tr"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "ru", "Русский", "famfamfam-flags ru"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "zh-CN", "简体中文", "famfamfam-flags cn"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "es-MX", "Español México", "famfamfam-flags mx"),
           // new ApplicationLanguage(null, "ja", "日本語", "famfamfam-flags jp")
       };
   }
   ```
2. If you have seeded before, remove the entries from the `AbpLanguages` table in the database.
3. Comment out this line in [Account/_Layout.cshtml](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/0380faf88edfbd8e2d86d6924e62f32781b13cfe/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Views/Account/_Layout.cshtml#L72) to disable language selection before login:

   ```
   @*<vc:account-languages></vc:account-languages>*@
   ```
4. Comment out this line in [Shared/_Layout.cshtml](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/9a1b9075e803f132f4da2cb20940246c0865b848/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml#L117) to disable language selection after login:

   ```
   @*@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(TopBarLanguageSwitchViewComponent))*@
   ```